# How can I observe changes to Night Shift on macOS / iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, iphone-privateapi, night-shift

I'm looking for a way to determine when Night Shift has been enabled or disabled and perform an action based on that. I'm currently using the CBBlueLightClient header in the CoreBrightness framework to control Night Shift. Here's a partial header I'm using in my app:

```
@interface CBBlueLightClient : NSObject
- (BOOL)setStrength:(float)strength commit:(BOOL)commit;
- (BOOL)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
- (BOOL)getStrength:(float*)strength;
- (BOOL)getBlueLightStatus:(struct { BOOL x1; BOOL x2; BOOL x3; int x4; struct { struct { int x_1_2_1; int x_1_2_2; } x_5_1_1; struct {
 int x_2_2_1; int x_2_2_2; } x_5_1_2; } x5; unsigned long x6; }*)arg1;
 @end
```

CBBlueLightClient also has a notification block, `-
 (void)setStatusNotificationBlock:(id /* block */)arg1;` which I can't figure out how to use.

[Here's the full header for iOS.](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CBBlueLightClient.h) Everything I've tried works with macOS, including the notification block which seems to be there. I just can't figure out what kind of closure it's expecting.

Comment: I doubt Apple will expose something like that since nigh shift affects the system as a whole. They wouldn't want developers to change their app's display when that happens. I would love to see if there is an option though.

Comment: @adev I wouldn't expect Apple to make something like this easy to find but I'm hoping it's still possible.

Comment: Not easy to find normally means a private api. So if you do find it you can't use it in your app anyway (if you want your app on the App Store)

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, this uses the private CoreBrightness framework. It's for an app whose main purpose is to control Night Shift, so it really isn't an issue for me. I knew I wouldn't be able to distribute it on the App Store when I started.

Comment: Night Shift was introduced in macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (Build 16E144f and Public Beta 1) and have a minimum hardware/software requirements: MacBookPro9,x, iMac13,x Macmini6,x MacBookAir5,x MacPro6,x MacBook8,x. and obviusly macOS 10.12.4. Are you sure you have this requirements?

Comment: @Nate "Everything I've tried works with macOS, including the notification block"... So, you got this working on macOS? Or you're trying to figure out the notification block for both macOS and iOS? Is the header the same on both platforms?

Comment: @TheNextman I don't have the notification block working in either OS. I'm assuming the header is the same because I can't find the macOS header. I at least know that setStatusNotificationBlock method is present, but I don't know what type the closure is expecting. The other getter and setter methods are working fine and I haven't tested any of this on iOS.

Comment: @Nate is your goal to get this working on mac, iOS, or both?

Comment: @TheNextman Just Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just create a `void` notification block, and it will fire when night shift is enabled / disabled and when the night shift settings are changed. Inside the notification block you can query whether night shift is enabled or disabled.

```
CBBlueLightClient *client = [[CBBlueLightClient alloc] init];

void (^notificationBlock)() = ^() {
    StatusData status;
    [client getBlueLightStatus:&status];
    //... check status.enabled, status.active, etc);
};

[client setStatusNotificationBlock:notificationBlock];
```

It seems that the strength changing doesn't fire a notification. You could poll for that if you need to? It really depends what your use case is.

If you just want to know when it's been toggled, subscribe the notification as above and check the `.enabled` property.

The header I'm using:

```
@interface CBBlueLightClient : NSObject

typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int minute;
} Time;

typedef struct {
    Time fromTime;
    Time toTime;
} Schedule;

typedef struct {
    BOOL active;
    BOOL enabled;
    BOOL sunSchedulePermitted;
    int mode;
    Schedule schedule;
    unsigned long long disableFlags;
} StatusData;

- (void)setStatusNotificationBlock:(id /* block */)arg1;
- (BOOL)getBlueLightStatus:(StatusData *)arg1;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other APIs?

[CCUINightShiftSectionController](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/995b3bb9011192afcd70eed8fb73f1b6688c52f2/PrivateFrameworks/ControlCenterUI.framework/CCUINightShiftSectionController.h)

```
 (void)_getBlueLightStatus:(id /* block */)arg1;
 (void)_setNightShiftEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
```

[CFCBSetNightShiftMode](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/9c31ca2f66e1e349c3e389f30e44d090f5ec3441/PrivateFrameworks/SiriClientFlow.framework/CFCBSetNightShiftMode.h)

Comment: Neither of those headers has a notification block. I've already implemented getting and setting the state of Night Shift. I'm looking to get notifications from the system when Night Shift is toggled outside my app.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your implementation @Nate ?

Comment: @m177312 I'm currently using this in an open source app. Here's the header file: https://github.com/thompsonate/Shifty/blob/master/Shifty/CBBlueLightClient.h  I have a Swift wrapper around it in this file: https://github.com/thompsonate/Shifty/blob/c091f38c526f4ac8bf4be18265400882879d6bfc/Shifty/NightShiftManager.swift